# TypeScript alias for asserting value type for keyof

Tags: typescript, types, type-alias, keyof

Having trouble discovering if you can assert the value type of a property with a type alias.
Here's my example:

```js
    type Primitive = string | number | boolean; 

    function comparePrimitives(a:Primitive, b:Primitive): number { /*...*/ }

    export function fromKey<T extends object> (key: keyof T)
    {
        return function(a: T, b: T): number {
            return comparePrimitives(a[key], b[key]); // TS2345
        };
    }
```

The problem I'm having is, TS2345 occurs.
I want to be able to build a function signature that will only allow for `T[keyof T]` that are primitive values.

Answer (score 1):

Because of `comparePrimitives` arguments are `Primitive`s, then `T` should be extended from object with `Primitive` values.
Detailed in working code snippet:

```
type Primitive = string | number | boolean; 

function comparePrimitives(a:Primitive, b:Primitive): number { /*...*/ }

export function fromKey<T extends { [key: string]: Primitive }> (key: keyof T)
{
    return function(a: T, b: T): number {
        return comparePrimitives(a[key], b[key]); // no TS2345
    };
}
```

Comment: I like where you're going with this but that would mean that every property of T would have to be of a Primitive value.  Which creates a TS2344 error for anything that does not match.

Comment: Here's another question that might help...
Let's say we have a function:

`function hasMember (instance: any, property: string): boolean {}`

How could you type this function to be a type guard to result in `instance is { property: unknown }`.  Where 'property' is the key provided.

Equivalent to a type guard for `'x' in y`.

Comment: I think type alias `Pick<T, K extends keyof T>` might be of use.

Comment: I meant: I think type alias `Pick` or `Record` might be of use.

Comment: The important part is I'm trying to validate that only the requested key has a value type of Primitive.
I feel like I've gotten really close b using `Record` but I'm missing some advanced typing syntax.